# creating customized test task

Tags: scala, sbt, scalatest

I need to create a new taskKey for a special test method that would write the test results into a html file. What would be the best approach to achieve this? This is what I've done so far:

```
lazy val finalTest = taskKey[Unit]("full test")

finalTest := {
  testOptions += Tests.Argument(TestFrameworks.ScalaTest, "-h",
    (target.value / "html-test-report").getAbsolutePath)
  //execute test 
  //test.value would only setup a dependency on test
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it might be easier to define a custom config instead.

```
val custom = config("custom") extend Test
testOptions in Custom ++= Seq(Tests.Argument(...)) ++ Defaults.testTasks
```

then run

```
custom:test or custom:testOnly...
```